# Spring Maven org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc

Here is Stack:

```
Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping#0' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/mvc-config.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [com.pankanis.controller.CustomerController] for bean with name 'CustomerController' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/mvc-config.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.pankanis.controller.CustomerController
Related cause: org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [com.pankanis.controller.CustomerController] for bean with name 'CustomerController' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/mvc-config.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.pankanis.controller.CustomerController
Related cause: org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [com.pankanis.dao.CustomerDAO] for bean with name 'CustomerDAO' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/mvc-config.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.pankanis.dao.CustomerDAO
Related cause: org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [com.pankanis.model.Customer] for bean with name 'CustomerModel' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/mvc-config.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.pankanis.model.Customer
Related cause: org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [com.pankanis.service.CustomerServiceImpl] for bean with name 'CustomerServiceImpl' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/mvc-config.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.pankanis.service.CustomerServiceImpl
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:553)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:305)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:301)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:196)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:772)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:834)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:537)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:446)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:328)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4887)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5381)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [com.pankanis.controller.CustomerController] for bean with name 'CustomerController' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/mvc-config.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.pankanis.controller.CustomerController
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1351)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.determineTargetType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:628)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:597)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1444)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doGetBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:445)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:423)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:409)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBeanNamesForType(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1141)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractDetectingUrlHandlerMapping.detectHandlers(AbstractDetectingUrlHandlerMapping.java:75)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractDetectingUrlHandlerMapping.initApplicationContext(AbstractDetectingUrlHandlerMapping.java:58)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ApplicationObjectSupport.initApplicationContext(ApplicationObjectSupport.java:120)
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.WebApplicationObjectSupport.initApplicationContext(WebApplicationObjectSupport.java:76)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ApplicationObjectSupport.setApplicationContext(ApplicationObjectSupport.java:74)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ApplicationContextAwareProcessor.invokeAwareInterfaces(ApplicationContextAwareProcessor.java:119)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ApplicationContextAwareProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(ApplicationContextAwareProcessor.java:94)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:408)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1570)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545)
    ... 21 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.pankanis.controller.CustomerController
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1713)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1558)
    at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:250)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinition.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanDefinition.java:394)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doResolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1396)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1343)
    ... 38 more
```

My CustomerController :

```
package com.pankanis.controller;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

import com.pankanis.model.Customer;
import com.pankanis.service.*;

@RequestMapping("/customer")
public class CustomerController {

    CustomerController(){}
    @Autowired 
    private CustomerService serv;

    public CustomerService getServ() {
        return serv;
    }

    public void setServ(CustomerService serv) {
        this.serv = serv;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/addCustomer",method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public String AddCustomer(@RequestBody Customer cust,HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response)
    {       

        String CustomerId = serv.AddCustomer(cust);     
        return CustomerId;          
    }
}
```

My mvc-config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <!-- Uncomment and your base-package here: <context:component-scan base-package="org.springframework.samples.web"/> -->



    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <!-- Example: a logical view name of 'showMessage' is mapped to '/WEB-INF/jsp/showMessage.jsp' -->
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/view/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>



        <bean
            class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping" />

        <bean id="CustomerController" class="com.pankanis.controller.CustomerController">
            <property name="serv" ref="CustomerServiceImpl"></property>
        </bean>

        <bean id="CustomerDAO" class="com.pankanis.dao.CustomerDAO"></bean>

        <bean id="CustomerModel" class="com.pankanis.model.Customer"></bean>

        <bean id="CustomerServiceImpl" class="com.pankanis.service.CustomerServiceImpl">
            <property name="customerDAO" ref="CustomerDAO"></property>
        </bean>
    </beans>

My web.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">

    <display-name>SpringMavenWeb</display-name>

    <!-- - Location of the XML file that defines the root application context. 
        - Applied by ContextLoaderListener. -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/mvc-config.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>


    <!-- - Servlet that dispatches request to registered handlers (Controller 
        implementations). -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/mvc-config.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

        <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/customer/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

Comment: the root cause is: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.pankanis.controller.CustomerController. is this class deployed?

Answer (score 0):

Verify that the name of the requested class is correct and that the appropriate .jar file exists in your classpath. If not, you must explicitly add it to your application’s classpath.

In case the specified .jar file exists in your classpath then, your application’s classpath is getting overriden and you must find the exact classpath used by your application.

In case the exception is caused by a third party class, you must identify the class that throws the exception and then, add the missing .jar files in your classpath.

Hope that helped.

Answer (score -1):

Try making your CustomerController constructor public.

Comment: Thanks @Joeri . But still same error is coming.
I have added public constructor for my controller and Service Implementation,Model.But still same error is coming